# References for generating Pythagorean triple using complex number

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am trying to learn the proof of generating Pythagorean triple using ring Gaussian Integer $\mathbb{z}[i]$. I am looking for references, preferably book where I could learn more about it. It is a plus if the book actually contains the proof of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about a google search for gaussian integer pythagorean triple? https://www.google.com/search?q=gaussian+integers+pythagorean+triple&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: @EthanBolker I have, but most of the results is notes from lecture, slides, or even research article ( which is above my head), that's is why I stated that I was looking for a book.